# How to filter data from relational table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have three table one is `orders` table and another is `order_status` table and another is `status` table. Purpose of `order_status` table is to keep a track order's events. My table has the following column.

Order table

```
----------------------------
id | ref_num | name | email |
-----------------------------
```

Order status table has

```
---------------------------
order_id | status_id
---------------------
```

My models are like this 
**Order model**

```
 public function orderStatus(){
        return $this->hasMany(OrderStatus::class');
    }
```

**Order status model**

```
  public function detail(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Status::class,'status_id','id');
    }

    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
```

Now i want to get all those order which are still pending. 
How can i do so ?

I tried to retrive like this but it failed

```
 $data['orders']= Order::with(['orderStatus' =>function($q){
                $q->with('detail')->latest()->where('status_id',2);
            }])->latest()->take(10)->get()->toArray();
```

This return only one after that it does not.

Can  anyone please tell me how can i sort this one ??
Thanks

PS:: one order can have multiple status such as unpaid, pending, packageging, in transit and so on but in sequence ofcouse

I added order status table image.. As u can see **E7E7FF0EB7** order number has two records 1,and 2 means it was pending and then later stage got delivered.or you can say got processed. where as E02EAEA4BE has only one record of status 1.  which means it is still pending.
So i want to get only those which are still pending.Not delivered. 
This kinda sound complicated, hope i able to explain properly what i am trying to do. 
[image]

Comment: try this `$data['orders']= Order::with('orderStatus' =>function($q){
                $q->where('status_id',2);
            })->latest()->take(10)->get()->toArray();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model relations should be changed to a proper many to many. The schemas look correct so I'd make the following changes:

```
// Order model
public function statuses(){ 
    return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class); 
}

// Status model
public function orders(){ 
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class); 
}
```

This will pivot correctly on `order_status`.

To get pending orders the query would be:

```
Order::whereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
    // assuming a 'name' column on statuses table
    $query->where('name', 'pending');
    // or using dynamic where
    // $query->whereName('pending');
})->get();
```

Alternatively, add a scope to Order model:

```
public function scopePending($query) {
    return $query->with(['statuses' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'pending');
    });
});
```

Usable then as: `Order::pending();`

Comment: I like this query building, but its me empty object. Btw onemore thing that i like to ask . Since my order status table holds all the events of the order that is if an order that has been delivered it also hold its record when it got ordered, whtn its packed, when it shiped and when its delivered. In that case will it be possible to filter only those data who are not process to shipping etc still in pending phase ??

Comment: My bad this is showing data, But it also showing all those which are also deliverd

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Try this to get all those order which are still pending..

```
$data['orders'] =  Order::has('orderStatus', '=', 2)->whereHas('orderStatus', function ($q) {
            $q->where('status_id', 2);
        })->get()->toArray();
```

If there is two status records related to one order and one of the status value is 1 then this query will return the order record. You may update it with your exact conditions.(If you are sure that there will be only 2 status related to a order which is still pending then you may remove the second `whereHas`.

```
$data['orders'] =  Order::has('orderStatus', '=', 2)->get()->toArray();
```

**You may use the `many to many` relation as @DigitalDrifter suggested. I would also suggest that you should follow `many to many` relation**.

If you are using the `many to many` relation then you may try the below query..

```
Order::has('statuses', '=', 2)->WhereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'pending');
})->get();
```

or

```
Order::has('statuses', '=', 2)->get();
```

Comment: But this will give all the order with order status 2, if someorder has order status 2,3,4 then that one will also come.
I dont want that to happen i want only those which has status 1,2 will come

Comment: @user7747472 did you tried? Is it helpful? Or having any issue?

Comment: @ ab_ab ,hi ab its for some reason returning empty object,although i hv 3 recoeds in order status table

Comment: My bad, i made some mistake in pivot joining. i am getting data. But it also showing those which are delived

Comment: can you confirm that the delivered order which is returned with this query has only two records in the pivot table?

Comment: as per your update in question it seems that if the order is pending then there will be only one record in the pivot, in that case you should change the relation count to 1. ie, `Order::has('statuses', '=', 1)->get();`

Comment: Yes i did that, but its returning 2 data,Order id ***E7E7FF0EB7 *** which has been delivered aslo showing as pending order

Comment: Which relationship do you use? `has many` or `many to many`?  And which option in my answer do you use?

Comment: I used many to many and the 2nd one
`Order::has('statuses', '=', 1 )->WhereHas('statuses', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'pending');
})->get();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169733/discussion-between-ab-ab-and-user7747472).